# Creating a method that returns a certain group of integers from two different integer arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm not really sure how to word the question for the title but this post explains what I'm after. I apologize if my question is worded incorrectly.

In Java, how would I go about creating a method that returns the number of 'hippos' found in two different integer arrays:

```
int[] hippo1 = new int[100];

int[] hippo2 = new int[10000];
```

given that a 'hippo' is considered an integer that is 75 or above?

Would it be?

```
public static int calcNumberOfHippos(int[] hippos)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < hippos.length; i++)
    {
        if (hippos[i] >= 75)
        {
            return hippos[i];
        }    
    }
    int numHippos = (int)hippos.length;
    return numHippos;
}
```

I'm not sure if I should return hippos.length at the end. That's the only way I can get it to return something. I would really like to return hippos[i] but every time I try to return that out of the for loop it says that it doesn't recognize the variable i. It says Cannot find symbol variable i.

```
public static int calcNumberOfHippos(int[] hippos)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < hippos.length; i++)
    {
        if (hippos[i] >= 75)
        {
            return hippos[i];
        }    
    }
    return hippos[i];
}
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would return an `Array` of `int` with a size of two. The first index would hold one value, and the second would hold the second value.

Comment: In your method take two `int` `Array`s as input. In the body creat two counters. Use two for loops. One for each `Array` that you passed to the method. Use one counter in the if statement of the first for loop. Use the second counter in the if statement of the second loop. Create a new `int Array` with size 2. Store the first counter in index 0 and the second in index one. Finally, return the array of size two.

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Please be clear if this is so.

Comment: An edit to my statement above. You don't need to return an array of size two. I read your question wrong. All you have to return is `return counter1 + counter2`.

Comment: Eatel, your code was mostly fine. I took it and made a small change, and explained it in an answer below. If it's clear and helped you solve the problem, could you please accept the answer by clicking on the gray check mark next to it, making it green?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to calculate the number of hippos (how many members of the array are larger than 75), then this code could help:

```
public static int calcNumberOfHippos(int[] hippos) {
int numOfHippos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < hippos.length; i++) {
        if (hippos[i] >= 75)
        {
            numOfHippos++;
        }    
    }
    return numOfHippos;
}
```

The idea is to go over the array and count up every time a hippo is spotted. You don't need to return the first hippo that you see - which is what your original code would've done.

Answer (score 0):

```
int hippoCount = Arrays.stream(hippos).reduce(0, (acc, n) -> acc + (n >= 75 ? 1 : 0));
```

should do the trick.